# GraphQL & Mongoose Schema - How to store an array of mongoose objectId references to another type?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am currently developing a Pizza Ordering/Tracking system for my local pizzeria. As you can see below, I have the GraphQL types and Mongoose models defined. In my pizza, I have an array of toppings which I set to reference the topping model. My question is, what would my mutation definition and the call to that mutation with the required arguments look like?

I want my Pizza document in Mongoose to containt the relevant ToppingIds so I can reference other fields of that topping such as the name and price. Hope that's clear. Maybe an array is not the best way to approach this??

If there is a more efficient way to have toppings within the pizza model, pls do share.

GraphQL Types:

```
    type Topping {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        price: Float!
        createdAt: String!
    }
    type Pizza {
        id: ID!
        location: String!
        price: Float!
        toppings: [Topping]!
        createdAt: String!
        toppingCount: Int!
    }
```

Mongoose Models:

```
const pizzaSchema = new Schema({
    location: String,
    price: Number,
    toppings: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "toppings"
    },
    createdAt: String
});

const toppingSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    createdAt: String
});
```

So ideally when viewing a pizza in the database, it should look like:

```
_id: ObjectId("5fab2e6cc4b5e628685228f6")
> toppings:Array
[
    ObjectId("5fab2e6cc4b5e628685228f7")
    ObjectId("5fab2e6cc4b5e628685228f8")
]
location:"Barcelona"
price:123
createdAt:"12"
__v:0
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: My Mutation Type and Mutation Call/Args + Error Message

```
createPizza(pizzaInput: PizzaInput): Pizza!
input PizzaInput {
    location: String!
    price: Float!
    toppings: [ID]!
    createdAt: String!
}

mutation {
  createPizza(pizzaInput: {
    location:"Barcelona"
    price:12
    toppings: [
      "5faaca3129c74ff103d3ccaf"
      "5faaed887ac3c53010b8075b"
    ]
    createdAt:"AAAA"
  }){
    id
    price
    location
    toppings {
      id
    }
    createdAt
    toppingCount
  }
}
```

Error Message:
"ID cannot represent value: <Buffer 5f aa ca 31 29 c7 4f f1 03 d3 cc af>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'll need the toppings value in the pizzaSchema to reflect that it is an array. Currently, it is just defined as an object like this:

```
    toppings: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "toppings"
    },
```

Instead of (note the brackets indicating an array):

```
    toppings: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "toppings"
    }],
```

Or in full, it should look like this:

```
const pizzaSchema = new Schema({
    location: String,
    price: Number,
    toppings: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "toppings"
    }],
    createdAt: String
});
```

Update after [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64829947/2):

Do you have a resolver defined for Pizza.toppings? I'm guessing that you're missing something like this in your resolvers map:

```js
  Pizza: {
    toppings: (parent) => {
      const obj_ids = parent.toppings.map((id) => ObjectId(id));
      return Topping.find({ _id: { $in: obj_ids } });
    },
  }
```

I'm not a GraphQL expert so I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way to have toppings within the pizza model, but based on a test I did adding the above resolver gets passed the "ID cannot represent value..." issue.

Comment: Thanks, I actually changed that right after posting. What would the GraphQL mutation look like & what would calling the mutation in Playground look like? This is really what I'm stuck on :(

Comment: @alanphil can you edit your question to include the type of mutation you are trying to perform, what you're currently trying to use, and the error message you are getting?

Comment: The question has been updated to include the requested!

Comment: @alanphil that will depend on what you're using for the GraphQL server (assuming something like: express-graphql, apollo-server-express, etc.).

Comment: After a week of trying to fix this, I appreciate you.

SOLUTION: I created a Pizza.toppings resolver and the Pizza now has an array of reference to many toppings.